# How to request authorization code for AuthorizationCodeCredential

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

Disclaimer: This is a continue from my previous question "[how-to-set-scope-when-call-microsoft-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867754/how-to-set-scope-when-call-microsoft-graph-api)"

I am learning to call Microsoft Graph API in Java for my project. Current task is to post a message on a channel.

My current code is as below:

```
ClientSecretCredential _credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().clientId(clientId).clientSecret(secretValue).tenantId(tenantId).build();
TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(graphUserScopes, _credential);
GraphServiceClient<Request>_client = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.content = message;
chatMessage.body = body;

_client.teams(teamId).channels(channelId).messages().buildRequest().post(chatMessage);
```

I have come to learn that ClientSecretCredential is for "Application" type of action only, and "send channel message" require a "Delegated" type. I think about trying AuthorizationCodeCredential class, but do not know how to request "authorizationCode" like in this link: [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider)

Can anyone help me with code to get "authorizationCode"?

Comment: Please check this doc for Requesting an authorization code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code

Comment: @MehtabSiddique Thanks for the reply. I have already read it, but it all about the concept and no sample code on how to do it using MS Graph SDK.